# Selenium Webdriver drag and drop not working in chrome version 46 but works in firefox

Tags: java, selenium

The code execute successfully but the drag and drop is not performing in chrome. please find the code below which i tried

```
WebElement From = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/reporting-layout/div/ui-view/add-statistics/div/statistics-query-builder/div/div[1]/selected-entities/div/div[2]/a[1]/span"));
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("droppable-column-container")));
WebElement To = driver.findElement(By.id("droppable-column-container"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(From)
.moveToElement(To)
.release(To)
.build();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
dragAndDrop.perform();
```

can someone help me in this please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code.

```
WebElement from = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/reporting-layout/div/ui-view/add-statistics/div/statistics-query-builder/div/div[1]/selected-entities/div/div[2]/a[1]/span"));            
WebElement to = driver.findElement(By.id("droppable-column-container"));

Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.clickAndHold(from).build().perform();
Thread.sleep(4000);
act.clickAndHold(to).moveToElement(to).release(to).build().perform();
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

Comment: Does my answer is `helped` you? if it does then please mark this answer as `Accepted`.